# Alternative to the MegaProtoUser in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

In Lift, the entire `ProtoUser` construct is quite awesome, amazing what it does for you, most of the advantages (like many things in Lift, unfortunately) undocumented.

There is just one problem: It holds data I don't need and even data I don't want. For example, I want my user to login by a nickname, and I don't need to know his location, locale or first/last name. But at sign-up, I require information that is not displayed on the standard sign-up page.

My first idea would be to re-write my own User trait, but then I would have to re-write all the session-ing code, authorisation, etc. Is there an alternative already? Or is it possible to alter the `ProtoUser` to have my own sign-up and login pages, as well as only my necessary data?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Check out this recent discussion on the liftweb group http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/cf396f89a4304beb/e74683995641e67e?lnk=gst&q=ProtoUser#e74683995641e67e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any easy way to remove any of the fields in ProtoUser but one option would be to look into the fieldOrder method in ProtoUser, I believe that defines the fields that protoUser uses. As to the sign up problem there is a method signUpFields that lets you override what fields you require at sign up like so

`override def signupFields = email :: userName :: password :: Nil`

Assuming you define your own userName object. There is also a similar method for editFields, this doesn't actually solve the problem of removing fields that it keeps track of but perhaps fieldOrder might do something, another suggestion I would have is to look at the source of Proto User and see if you can maybe override the mapped objects and make mapper ignore them somehow. This is still just a way of working around Proto User to avoid having to rewrite a lot of the code it contains.

Comment: This seems to work all right for the sign-up, but when editing the user, I get the very same standard fields as before. And logging only ever works with the email...

Comment: yea there is a separate method called editFields for the edit user page. As far as logging in with the username I do not know how to change that one. You would have to override some of the methods of proto-user for that.